# NUnit Setup attribute that can be used for specific tests

Tags: .net, nunit

NUnit has a `[OneTimeSetUp]` which is run once for all tests in a fixture, and a `[SetUp]` which is run before each test in the fixture.

I have a fixture/class which has some methods which require certain setup, and some that don't. The obvious approaches are

- include the specific setup in each test, but that is massive duplication, or
- move those tests to a separate fixture, but that scatters my code and I don't like that

Is there something like this:

```
[Test]
[SetupFoo]     //  this is what I'm after 
public void test_that_requires_foo_to_be_setup { /* ... */ }

[Test]
[SetupFoo]     //  this is what I'm after 
public void another_test_that_requires_foo { /* ... */ }

[Test]
public void test_that_doesnt_require_foo { /* ... */ }
```

That `[SetupFoo]` attribute would perform setup only for tests decorated with it.

I know this doesn't exist, but is there something similar that achieves this goal?

Comment: It depends on what kind of setup you need to do, but for some cases [Action Attributes](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Action-Attributes) can be suitable.

Comment: Why not have two private methods in the fixture that do the different setups? Then you call one method for one setup and the other for the other. That way it's only one extra line of code in each test, and minimizes code duplication (It's no worse than the test setup attribute line would be.

Comment: @AbeHeward That is a valid option, but you can't see at a glance what is going on without reading the test. The point of the attributes is that you have that kind of readability.